# sequence coverage algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve the following problem:

Given the sequence `n` containing digits from `0` to `9` and `m` other sequences, find the smallest (containing the lowest amount) series of sequences that is equal to `n`.

**Example**

```
n = 123456
m1 = 12
m2 = 34
m3 = 56
m4 = 3456
output = m1 + m4 = 123456
```

**Things I've thought of so far**

Basic greedy technique using FSM or a trie tree to find the longest sequence fitting in the beginning:

```
while n not null
    longest = the longest sequence fitting in the beginning of n
    print longest
    n = n - longest
```

*Counterexample*

```
n = 123456
m1 = 12
m2 = 1
m3 = 23456
m4 = 3
m5 = 4
m6 = 5
m7 = 6
algorithm will find m1 + m4 + m5 + m6 + m7 (12 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6)
algorithm should find m2 + m3 (1 + 23456)
```

Another greedy method

```
array = {n} #this represents words to be matched
while array not empty
    (word, index) = find longest sequence covering part of any word in array and its index
    split array[index] into two words - first before found word, second after it
    if any of those split items is null
        remove it
```

*Counterexample*

```
n = 12345678
m1 = 3456
m2 = 1
m3 = 2
m4 = 7
m5 = 8
m6 = 123
m7 = 45
m8 = 678
algorithm will find m2 + m3 + m1 + m4 + m5 (1 + 2 + 3456 + 7 + 8)
algorithm should find m6 + m7 + m8 (123 + 45 + 678)
```

Comment: I don't understand your statement of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic programming to compute the result step by step.

Lets define s(i) the shortest sequence which generate the first i chars of n.

With the data of the last example, the values of s(i) are :

```
s(0) = { }    
s(1) = { m2 }
s(2) = { m2 + m3 }
s(3) = { m6 }
s(4) = { }       (no sequence can generate "1234")
s(5) = { m6 + m7 }
s(6) = { m2 + m3 + m1 }
s(7) = { m2 + m3 + m1 + m4 }
s(8) = { m6 + m7 + m8 }
```

You have to compute `s(1)` to `s(n)` in order. At each step `i` you look to all the sequences starting from `s(0)` to `s(i-1)` and keep the shortest.

For example, for `s(8)`, you find that you have two solutions :

```
s(8) = s(5) + m8
s(8) = s(7) + m5
```

And you keep the shortest.

The algorithm :

```
function computeBestSequence(word, list of subsequences m)

let s(0) :=  {}
for i from 1 to n     // We will compute s(i)
   let minSize := +inf.
   for j from 0 to i - 1        
      for all sequences mx from m1 to m9
         if s(j) + mx = the first i char of word
             if size of s(j) + mx is less than minSize
                minSize := size of s(j) + mx
                s(i) := s(j) + mx
```

---

Edit :

The algorithm can be simplified to use only two loops :

```
let s(0) :=  {}
for i from 1 to n     // We will compute s(i)
   let minSize := +inf.
   for all sequences mx from m1 to m9
      let j := i - mx.length
      if s(j) + mx = the first i char of word
          if size of s(j) + mx is less than minSize
              minSize := size of s(j) + mx
              s(i) := s(j) + mx
```

Comment: What's the complexity of this algorithm? Is it Θ(m * n^2)?

Comment: Yes it is. But it can be simplified to run in O(m * n). I've updated the response to add the (faster) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Based on obourgains answer java code of his edit version:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class BestSequence {

public static List<String> match(String word, List<String> subsequences) {
    int n = word.length();

    //let s(0) :=  {}
    List<List<String>> s = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        s.add(new LinkedList<>());

    //for i from 1 to n
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        //let minSize := +inf.
        int minSize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        //for all sequences mx from m1 to m9
        for(String mx : subsequences) {
            //let j := i - mx.length
            int j = i - mx.length();

            if(j < 0)
                continue;

            //if s(j) + mx = the first i char of word
            if(word.substring(0, i).equals(concat(s.get(j)) + mx)) {
                //if size of s(j) + mx is less than minSize
                if(s.get(j).size() + 1 < minSize) {
                    //minSize := size of s(j) + mx
                    minSize = s.get(j).size() + 1;
                    //s(i) := s(j) + mx
                    List<String> sj = new LinkedList<>(s.get(j));
                    sj.add(mx);
                    s.set(i, sj);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s.get(n);
}

private static String concat(List<String> strs) {
    String s = "";
    for(String str : strs) {
        s += str;
    }
    return s;
}

}
```

The test:

```
@Test
public void bestSequenceTest() {
    List<String> l = BestSequence.match("123456", Arrays.asList("12", "34", "56", "3456"));
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

The output:

```
[12, 3456]
```